# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username' on a project which has been working fine for some time

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a project and the models seemed to work fine until I added a feedback field in models. The data in the UserProfile table cannot be accessed and returns the above error.

models.py

```
Roles = (
('sales', 'SALES'),
('operations', 'OPERATIONS'),
('cashier', 'CASHIER'),
('frontdesk', 'FRONTDESK'),
('client', 'CLIENT'),
```

)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Roles, default='client')
feedback = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

view for feedback:

```
@login_required
def feedback(request):
form = FeedbackForm()

if request.method =='POST':

    form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = FeedbackForm.save()
return render(request, 'NewApp/feedback.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields =   ('first_name','last_name','username','email','password')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "password and confirm_password does not match"
            )


class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('role',)

class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile 
        fields = ('feedback',)
```

Answer (score 0):

The user on the UserProfile model can be nullable on database.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
```

And the method **str** is using this user to print the username

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

You need to check if the user is none:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.user:
        return self.user.username

    return '{} {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)
```

Comment: It says __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Comment: Ups, sorry I update the code now if you don't have any user associated to the UserProfile will show UserProfile 1, UserProfile 2 ...